# Faster way to sort arrays of array in vb6

Tags: sorting, vb6, swap, quicksort

What I have here works fine for data which is 10 row bytes x 10 column bytes =100 elements for example.
But now I tried it on 256 row bytes x 256 column bytes = 65536 elements and it's taking about 30 minutes to sort the rows in proper lexicographical order. Anyway to optimize this function so it could take maybe 5 seconds maximum to complete.

I know I have to use some other sorting algorithm but I cannot really figure out what to do.

```
Function SortArrayOfArraysLexicoGraphically(ByRef data() As Byte) As Byte()
Dim lexicoGraphicalIndexes() As Byte

Dim dataSize As Long
dataSize = UBound(data) + 1
Dim squareRootMinusOne As Integer
Dim squareRoot As Integer
squareRoot = Sqr(dataSize)
squareRootMinusOne = squareRoot - 1

ReDim lexicoGraphicalIndexes(squareRootMinusOne)

Dim columnStart As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim column As Long
Dim rowSwapped As Boolean

For columnStart = 0 To UBound(lexicoGraphicalIndexes)
    lexicoGraphicalIndexes(columnStart) = columnStart
Next columnStart

'start column from the last element from the row and go backwards to first element in that row.
For columnStart = squareRootMinusOne To 0 Step -1
    Do
        rowSwapped = False
        Do
             If data((row * squareRoot) + columnStart) > data(((row + 1) * squareRoot) + columnStart) Then

                'Swaps a full row byte by byte.
                For column = 0 To squareRootMinusOne
                    Call SwapBytes(data, (row * squareRoot) + column, ((row + 1) * squareRoot) + column)
                Next column
                Call SwapBytes(lexicoGraphicalIndexes, row, row + 1)
                rowSwapped = True
            End If
            row = row + 1
        Loop Until row > squareRootMinusOne - 1
        row = 0
    Loop Until rowSwapped = False
Next columnStart

'returns a byte array of sorted indexes.
SortArrayOfArraysLexicoGraphically = lexicoGraphicalIndexes
End Function

Public Sub SwapBytes(data() As Byte, firstIndex As Long, secondIndex As Long)
    Dim tmpFirstByte As Byte
    tmpFirstByte = data(firstIndex)
    data(firstIndex) = data(secondIndex)
    data(secondIndex) = tmpFirstByte
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slow step in this is the copying, byte by byte, in a loop. I would take advantage of the RtlMoveMemory API call (often called CopyMemory). This does a block memory copy which is a lot faster. I also declare a module level array to act as the temporary buffer in the row swap. You could probably just merge the two procedures below, to make it self-contained:

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "Kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal pDest As Long, ByVal pSrc As Long, ByVal nCount As Long)

Private m_bytTemp() As Byte


Function SortArrayOfArraysLexicoGraphically2(ByRef data() As Byte) As Byte()

    Dim lexicoGraphicalIndexes() As Byte
    Dim dataSize As Long
    Dim squareRootMinusOne As Integer
    Dim squareRoot As Integer
    Dim columnStart As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim column As Long
    Dim rowSwapped As Boolean

    dataSize = UBound(data) + 1
    squareRoot = Sqr(dataSize)
    ReDim m_bytTemp(1 To squareRoot)
    squareRootMinusOne = squareRoot - 1
    ReDim lexicoGraphicalIndexes(squareRootMinusOne)

    For columnStart = 0 To UBound(lexicoGraphicalIndexes)
        lexicoGraphicalIndexes(columnStart) = columnStart
    Next columnStart

    'start column from the last element from the row and go backwards to first element in that row.
    For columnStart = squareRootMinusOne To 0 Step -1
        Do
            rowSwapped = False
            Do
                If data((row * squareRoot) + columnStart) > data(((row + 1) * squareRoot) + columnStart) Then
                    'Swaps a full row in a few copies.
                    SwapMultipleBytes data, (row * squareRoot), ((row + 1) * squareRoot), squareRoot
                    Call SwapBytes(lexicoGraphicalIndexes, row, row + 1)
                    rowSwapped = True
                End If
                row = row + 1
            Loop Until row > squareRootMinusOne - 1
            row = 0
        Loop Until rowSwapped = False
    Next columnStart

    'returns a byte array of sorted indexes.
    SortArrayOfArraysLexicoGraphically2 = lexicoGraphicalIndexes
End Function

Public Sub SwapMultipleBytes(ByRef data() As Byte, ByVal firstIndex As Long, ByVal secondIndex As Long, ByVal nCount As Long)

    CopyMemory VarPtr(m_bytTemp(1)), VarPtr(data(firstIndex)), nCount
    CopyMemory VarPtr(data(firstIndex)), VarPtr(data(secondIndex)), nCount
    CopyMemory VarPtr(data(secondIndex)), VarPtr(m_bytTemp(1)), nCount

End Sub
```

Comment: Yup that did it.. now the whole process is under a second!. Who knew visual basic byte by byte copying was so slow!.

Comment: Actually, it is more likely it is the array access which is the slowest thing. Behind the scenes, VB arrays are a special Automation type called SAFEARRAY. Whenever you access (read or write) an element in this array, it has to do a boundary check based on the LBound and UBound values. You can prevent this by checking the advanced compilation option "Remove Array Bounds Checks". However, the RtlMoveMemory API does more than this - I guess that it copies 32 bits at a time, rather than 8 bits - more efficient on a 32-bit compatible processor.